# Center items in list (CSS)

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming, html-lists

I need to center the items on a list of my social-media menu (the 4 icons under the title on the sidebar).
I got to made them distribute evenly (each item width is 25% since I have 4), the "ul" is displayed as table.
However, the icons inside each "li" stick to the left ! Any ideas ? THANKS !

http://www.blogderod.com/

```
.social-navigation {
margin: 0 15% 10%;
display: table;
width: 70%;
}

.social-navigation li {
display: inline-block;
text-align: center;
float: none;
width: 25%;
}
```

Comment: please post relevant html css js codes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following to your CSS:

```
.social-navigation a,
.social-navigation a:before {
    width: 100%;
}
```

This makes both the link and the social icon take up the full width of the `li`, allowing them both to centre correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Add "text-align: center;" on the LIs and make the links inside the LIs "display: inline-block;".

Comment: You should make the width of the links 24px as well. They are currently much larger than they need to be, offsetting the horizontal placement of it.

Answer (score 0):

Edit this class like this:

```
.social-navigation a:before {
content: "\f415";
font-size: 24px;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 20px;
```

Change top/left position as you wish.

Answer (score 0):

Make this changes in your CSS

```
media="all"
.social-navigation a:before {
content: "\f415";
font-size: 24px;
/* position: absolute; */
/* top: 0; */
/* left: 0; */
}
```

Hope that helps